# Regular expression to match digits

Tags: regex

My test string:

```
Continuity:pass_mV[12]#x_u_123
```

My regular expression:

```
(?P<VOL>.*):.*(?P<DIGIT>[\d]+)]#(?P<PIN>.*)$
```

My matches:

```
VOL Continuity
DIGIT   2
PIN x_u_123
```

My intention matches:

```
VOL Continuity
DIGIT   12
PIN x_u_123
```

The digits in the bracket should only be `1` or `2`.

Can somebody help with modifying my regular expression to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, change `.*([\d]+)]` to `.*\[(\d+).*`:

```
(?P<VOL>.*):.*\[(?P<DIGIT>\d+).*#(?P<PIN>.*)$
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/9lHCLApODPYwnF).

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```regex
(?P<VOL>.*):.*\[(?P<DIGIT>[1-2]+)\]#(?P<PIN>.*)$
```

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer too, but I had to give the best answer to the earliest one.